# When a subspace of normal spaces is normal

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

It is well known that a closed subspace of a normal space is normal. I am looking for a condition $*$, such that the following statement is true.

A subspace of a normal space is normal if and only if it has $*$  condition.

> By a normal space, we mean a Hausdorff space that any two disjoint closed subsets contained in two disjoint open subsets.

Comment: One is that any two closed disjoint closed subsets of $X$ have disjoint closures in some compactification of $X.$

Comment: Is there any reference for your comment?

Comment: Probably in General Topology by Engelking. Chapter 3.Section 3.5: Compactifications. You may also want to see Theorem 2.1.7 (Chapter 2, Section 1: Subpspaces) on hereditary normality.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "completely normal space":

"A completely normal space or a hereditarily normal space is a topological space X such that every subspace of X with subspace topology is a normal space. It turns out that X is completely normal if and only if every two separated sets can be separated by neighbourhoods." - Wikipedia

and here is a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290279/showing-that-a-space-is-completely-normal-iff-every-subspace-is-normal).