# Perfectly Normal Space implies Completely Normal Space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

The question I am thinking of is:
*If a space is perfectly normal then it is completely normal.* 
(**Perfectly Normal** means that for each closed $A$ there is a function $f: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ that $f|_A=0$ and $f(x)>0$ else where. **Completely Normal** means that each subset of topological space $X$ is Normal)

I am aware of the proof of finding a function $h$ that separates each $A, B$ with the property of $\overline A \cap B =\emptyset$ and $ A \cap \overline B =\emptyset$. You can find this proof here:
[show that a perfectly normal space is completely normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486406/show-that-a-perfectly-normal-space-is-completely-normal)

In the following, I will put my another attempt. I will be thankful if let me know if there is any error in it. First, we should be aware of the two following lemmas that make another way of understanding *Perfectly Normal* and *Completely Normal*.( I will use only Lemma 1)

**Lemma 1:** A space $X$ is perfectly Normal iff all of its closed subsets are $G_{\delta}$. (the idea of proof can be found  [$(X,\mathscr T)$ is perfectly normal iff it is normal and each closed subsets of $X$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set.(Without using Urysohn lemma)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134663/x-mathscr-t-is-perfectly-normal-iff-it-is-normal-and-each-closed-subsets-of))
**Lemma 2:** A space $X$ is Completely Normal iff for each two subsets of $X$ that $\overline A \cap B =\emptyset$ and $ A \cap \overline B =\emptyset$, then there are open sets that separate them. ([Showing that a space is completely normal iff every subspace is normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290279/showing-that-a-space-is-completely-normal-iff-every-subspace-is-normal?rq=1))

Now I can use these two lemmas for the proof. I know that $X$ is Perfectly Normal, so each closed sets in it is $G_{\delta}$( *the intersection of countable open sets*).

**Lemma 3:** Every subsets of *Perfectly Normal* topological space is *Perfectly Normal*.
*Proof.* We need to prove that each closed sets in subspace $Y \subset X$ is intersection of countable opens in $Y$. We assume $A \subseteq Y$ closed then we have $\overline A \cap Y=A$( we take the closure in $X$). We know $X$ is *Perfectly Normal*, and $\overline A$ is closed in X. Thus $\overline A = \cap_{i=1}^{\infty}U_i$, which each $U_i$ is open in $X$. As a result:
$$ A = \overline A \cap Y = (\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}U_i) \cap Y=\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}(U_i\cap Y)=\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}V_i$$
With assuming that $V_i= U_i\cap Y$, and this means that $V_i$ is open in $Y$. By the above result, $Y$ is *Perfectly Normal* too. $\blacksquare$

As a result of Lemma 3, each subset of *Perfectly Normal* space $X$ is *Perfectly Normal*, and therefore Normal!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show that a perfectly normal space is completely normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486406/show-that-a-perfectly-normal-space-is-completely-normal)